# Convergence in a topology

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

Consider the topological space $(\mathbb{R},\tau)$ where $\tau = \{A \subset \mathbb{R}:\exists N \in \mathbb{N} ,\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n\geq N: \frac{1}{n} \in A\}\cup \{\emptyset\}$. I am trying to prove that $\{-\frac{1}{n}\}_n$ converges to nothing. Open sets in this topology are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ which contain a "tail" of the sequence $\{1/n\}_n$, so they are either the set $\{1/n: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ or intervals which have 0 on the left and anything greater than 0 on the right, like $(0,a)$, $[0,a)$, $(0,a]$, and $[0,a]$.

Clearly, therefore, $\{-1/n\}_n$ cannot converge to any $x\geq 0$ because the sequence never enters any open sets containing those values of $x$. But for $x<0$, I just wanted to make sure I was correct in the following argument. Consider the open set $\{x\}\cup (0,1)$. (That's open, right?). The sequence $\{-1/n\}_n$ never enters $\{x\}\cup (0,1)$ (unless $x$ has the form $1/n$, but then it immediately leaves) after some index $n\in \mathbb{N}$ for every $x < 0$, so it cannot converge for any $x<0$. The sequence does not converge to any $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're generally right, but here are a few comments:

1) Your characterization of open sets as ones "that contain a tail of the sequence $\{1/n\}$" is really good, but the next part about intervals is way too restrictive. For example, $\mathbb{Q}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in this topology. I think just leaving it at "contains a tail ..." is good.

2) The argument that it has no limit $x \ge 0$ isn't so great. The statement "never enters any open set ..." is actually not true. $(-1, +\infty)$ is an open set containing every positive number, and the sequence certainly enters it. But to prove a point is not a limit of a sequence all you have to do is exhibit a single open neighborhood of that point that the sequence doesn't enter, and $[0,+\infty)$ is such an open set for any $x \ge 0$.

3) The idea for the argument for negative $x$ is perfect. The language is a tiny bit clunky; I'd say it would need to be improved for a submitted article, but it's good enough for homework.

Comment: Thank you so much for these comments! It is a final exam review problem, and I plan to write it much more formally than I have above. For 1), I hadn't even thought about $\mathbb{Q}$, so this helps a lot more with the intuition of this topology. For 2), I kinda skimped out on some detail, but what I have written is to consider the set $(0,x]$ which "works" for all $x\geq 0$, but $[0, \infty)$ is a much cleaner choice. For 3), I definitely agree, and I'll be writing it more formally.

Comment: Cool. Just to be super clear, on 2), your original argument says "the sequence never enters any open sets containing those values of $x$", and that's actually wrong and should lose you points. But in your comment it sounds like you're switching to exhibiting a particular open set (possibly depending on $x$) that excludes the sequence. That's a valid argument and I think your $(0,x]$ is just as good as my $[0,+\infty)$. Good luck.